# App-like back button flow, with back button in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, back

I have a web app (running Rails and jQuery Mobile) with a top navbar which gets a back arrow button to go to previous pages.

I have the following two page flows that go like this:

1) Home -> item -> item details

2) Favorites -> item -> item details

If I go from (Home or Favorites) only to the item page, I can easily just press the browser back button (or add a back link) to go back to Home or Favorites. Ok that's fine.

But if I go one step further to the item details page, then press the back button to the item page, then press the back button again, it goes back to the details page.

But what I want it to do, is to go to either the Home or Favorites page (which ever one I started at).

I have tried adding `data-rel="back" and data-direction="reverse"` to the back link, but it does not work as I explained above.

Any suggestions or best practice?

Comment: I have thought about creating a short-lived session variable to set as the "home" or "favorites" page... But not sure how I'd implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use history API to control push and popstates. This way you can easily control what to show if the user hits back or forward on the browser.

Comment: Any examples of a history API?